# Laravel SnappyPDF image attachment

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Im currently using **[barryvdh/laravel-snappy](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy)** to convert my data to pdf format.

The code i'm using is :

```
public function generate_pdf($id){
    $rfq = RFQ::find($id);

    $data = array(
        'rfq' => $rfq,
    );

    //return view('rfq.pdf')->with('rfq', $rfq);

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('rfq.pdf',$data)->setPaper('a4')->setOption('margin-bottom', 0);    
    return $pdf->download($rfq->rfq_no.'-'.date_timestamp_get(date_create()).'.pdf');
}
```

And then, I have to add an image to the pdf file. So i have to add this line to the `pdf.blade.php`  file.

`<img src="{{ asset('img/logo.png') }}">`

But then, the image isn't showing properly.

It's visible, but it's **OPACITY is very low, around 0.2**.

But when viewing the actual image file, and the one in the actual html template, everything's good.

I tried `<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ base64_encode(@file_get_contents(asset('img/logo.png'))) }}">`
 but still, it's the same.

Comment: try to give a fix width and height

Comment: @laravellevaral tried, but still the issue remains

Comment: try to use `src="{{public_path() . '/img/logo.png'}}"`

Comment: @Iosu just tried. not working.

Comment: Try this ``<style>img {opacity: 1.0; alpha(opacity=100);}</style>`` of course add code to ``$data`` at the top

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution using the next css tags (Only works with jpg images, with png the background turns black):

```
<img style="z-index: 100;position: relative;" src="img/logo.jpg">
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).